# Updated Weekly Comparison between two values

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to make an excel for keeping track of body weight.

On each SUNDAY, the new weight will be inputted by the user, this will go on for an infinite amount months. I want to be able to calculate the difference between last Sunday's input and the current Sunday's input when a new weight is inputted, then display the difference in a cell.

The problem is, I can do this for the first two inputs, but I want it so once you have 4 inputs, it will no longer use the 1st two weights for the calculation, but the 3rd and 4th, and same with 8 inputs, where it would use the 7th and 8th input for the calculation instead of 1st-6th and so on.

I have tried conditional formatting and if's, although it does not get the "use newest 2" effect I want. What could I use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a 'spare' column to the left of your weights. Let's take column A as the spare and then record your weights in column B. Allowing for column headings and generally laying things out nicely, let's say your first weight data is in cell B4, then the following week's data is in B5 and so on. In cell A4 enter the formula:

```
=A3+IF(B6=0,1,0)
```

Now copy this formula down for as many rows as you need in column A. Your formula to get the difference between the newest two weights is:

```
=VLOOKUP(2,A:B,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[EDIT - allowing for 'calendar' view]

For you calendar view you are going to need a spare row above your weight data. You could hide this row if you wanted. Allowing for blank cells between your inputs I would use a slightly different technique. In this spare row (e.g. cell D2) put the formula:

```
=C2+IF(D3=0,0,1)
```

Copy this formula all the way to the right. The formula for your newest difference calculation now becomes:

```
=HLOOKUP(MAX(2:2),2:3,2,FALSE)-HLOOKUP(MAX(2:2)-1,2:3,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: I currently have it set up like a calendar: [Here](https://snag.gy/bNKBta.jpg), could I apply the same technique to this format?

Answer (score 0):

If the entries will consistently be on a Sunday and on a weekly basis and you were happy to include the date in column A and your weight in column B then keep a rolling formula in column C:

In row 5: =b5-b4
In row 6: =b6-b5

This formula in column C can be dragged down using the small box in the bottom right of the cell and will automatically change the row number for you.